# How to Echo to a txt when echo is off?

Tags: batch-file

I want a user to enter a string which will be saved into a variable which will then be Echoed into a text file...

And this is what I've got:

```
set /p string = Enter string to add to the text file:
echo %string% > saves.txt
echo Added %string% to the text file
```

but in saves.txt it gives me:

```
Echo is off.
```

(I'm sorry if a similar topic has popped up like this but I'm new to programming and I wasn't sure what to get out of it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set /p string = Enter string to add to the text file:
             ^ here is the problem
```

As you are defining a variable with a space in its name, when you echo `%string%`, without space, you can not get the content of the variable. Change your code to

```
set /p "string= Enter string to add to the text file:"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't think that spaces mattered in batch files :P   I would voteUp if i had the reputation